# ACF Advanced Custom Field Multiplication returning 0 instead of the correct math answer

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to do all manner of things with the ACF Advanced Custom  fields. In this case I created two custom fields

```
<?php
$num1 = get_field('test_one');
$num2 =  get_field('test_two');
$num3 = $num1*$num2 ;
echo  "</br> Value is $num3" ; 
?>
```

test_one contains 2 as the default value, test_two contains 4
I am getting 0 as the result when clearly the field values should return something different.

What is going on here?

Comment: Show the result of `var_dump($num1, $num2);`

Comment: `bool(false) bool(false)`

Comment: Well that should answer the question what is going on pretty clearly. (And next time, please see to it that you do at least this much “debugging” before you come asking here.)

Comment: @DanstanOngubo  if you want to multiply the value but in code you have add "+" sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiplying Two numbers of Custom field value do as below:

1) add field in plugin page where you have to select type as "number" like [this](https://prnt.sc/q6kkn6)

2) Add below code in functions.php

```
function multiplynumber()
{
   $test_one = get_field('test_one', get_the_ID());
   $test_two = get_field('test_two', get_the_ID());
   $num3 = $test_two*$test_one ;
   echo  "</br> Value is".$num3 ; 
}

add_action('wp_head','multiplynumber');
```

You have to write post/page id where your field plugin showing in admin panel see this [image](https://prnt.sc/q6l0vj) where i have put condition in "page"

e.g from backend in sample-page i have write value in **"test_one" = 2** and **"test_two" = 4** see [here](https://prnt.sc/q6l3h4) then it will show multiply value in that front page see [here](https://prnt.sc/q6l4db) so you have to write that page ID in get_field function or you can also use

> get_the_ID()

as dynamic purpose